# How do I make Console.SetCursorPosition() scroll correctly in Linux Terminals?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET application as a homework for uni which requires me to list transactions.
The Console is set to a fixed size of 80x20. When listing more than 20 items, I was able to modify the screen buffer on Windows (to prevent seemingly endless scrolling and clunky behaviour) and Console.SetCursorposition() while navigating the list vertically to scroll all items up the screen as you move down in the list.

On Linux, while manual scrolling to the top with the mouse wheel is possible to view the full screen, whenever I use the arrow keys, I am being sent to the bottom of the screen again - Console.SetCursorPosition() seems to have no influence on that.

The relevant code that makes this work on Windows is as follows:

```cs
Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);
Console.SetCursorPosition(0,5 + selectedIndex + 2);

var key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
switch (key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
        selectedIndex = (selectedIndex > 0) ? selectedIndex - 1 : transactions.Count - 1;
        if(selectedIndex > 0) Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
        selectedIndex = (selectedIndex < transactions.Count - 1) ? selectedIndex + 1 : 0;
        if(selectedIndex < transactions.Count - 1) Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop + 1);
        break;
```

I tried debuggin to see the value of the cursor position, and the behaviour is the same as on Windows. I am hoping that, with your help, I can achieve the same behaviour as on Windows. Unfortunately, I cannot attach a video here, I hope these few screenshots help visualising the correct behaviour:

[When entering list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RlrZ.png)

[As you scroll further down, the screen follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4mrB.png)

[When reaching the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBhMo.png)

On Linux (tested in both Alacritty and XTerm), you only ever get the bottom view, alongside the occasional visual glitch showing the top of the screen for a split second.

Comment: Check if transactionCount is greater than zero.  The error may not be with the posted code but instead you do not have any data.  If transactionCount is not greater than zero you will have issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the transaction count is another problem that I discovered, and I will take care of it. But as you can see in the screenshot, the issue is unrelated to the amount of transactions, but related to the way that windows scrolls the items vs. how Linux fails to do that.

Comment: Fix the Transaction Count.  When using the down arrow if you are outside the range you should set Cursor position to the last item, not the first.   I would add an output for testing a see if the selected index makes sense.  I think the Linux is not working because you have no data, and not the scrolling method.

Comment: As mentioned before, on Windows everything works as it should. Debugging shows the index to be correct, the cursor position to be correct. The data you see in the screenshot is actually stored. When hitting enter, the right entry is opened for a detailed view. The issue I'm having specifically is: Say you have 40 lines, but the terminal's size is set to 20 lines. On windows, when setting the cursor position to 21, it automatically scrolls the terminal down - on Linux, it does not, it just stays at the bottom because that's the last line that is printed every loop iteration.